# D3 append div with id

Tags: html, d3.js

I want to add a div with a certain id to another div. Is this possible?

My suggestion was following:

```
<div class="clearfix">
</div>

<script>
var name = "xy";
var div = d3.select(".clearfix")
    .append("div#area" + name) 
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: `d3.select(".clearfix").append("div").attr("name", "area" + name);`

Comment: why you want to append another div here, you can directly include the name here??? is there any reason

Answer (score -2):

You can create it using jQuery Append. Below is the simple script.

```
var $newdiv1 = $( "<div id='object1'/>" );
$newdiv1.text("New Div Content");
$(".clearfix").append($newdiv1);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/phzwebog/2/

Option 2:

```
$(".clearfix").append("<div id='object1'>hello world</div>");
```

Comment: Why it is down voted? It is working as per your need.. Any specific reason?

Comment: I am the one that downvoted, and sorry for forgetting to leave a comment. The reason is that the OP does not ask for a jQuery solution but a D3.js one. So, no, it is not working as per the OP needs.